# How to open JPEG2000 files in Photoshop 2021

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-conversion, jpeg

I used to have a plugin in photoshop that reads jp2 / JPEG2000 files. Since the latest update it seems to be broken. Photoshop can not read them anymore. It says the file format module can not interpret the file. What could be the solution?

Comment: Photoshop doesn't need a plugin to read [or write] jp2 files.

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue- I just opened a jpeg2000 (.jp2) in version 22.0.0 (Photoshop 2021) on a mac- it worked fine natively- no plug in necessary. A status bar came up saying "reading jpeg2000 format" then it opened. Maybe there is another issue with the particular files you are trying to open ?

Comment: Sounds like a bad/corrupt file, not a problem with Photoshop. Photoshop has had native JPG2000 support for some time.

Comment: I tested a jp2 file on Mac & Windows. The Mac itself can see it natively & open it in Preview or even just QuickLook. Windows has no idea what it is. [I don't have Photoshop on Windows to double-check]

Comment: Thank you guys. There might be an issue with the file then. I use Mac so the ability of Mac to open jp2 is definitely a work around for that file. The file is at least not so corrupt that mac wouldn't read it. So I'm curious why Photoshop does not. It would ease my workflow if I could open in straight in Photoshop.

Comment: I've been a Mac user for more than 30 years.. it's NOT your Mac. The file was bad.. it happens. Which is why backups are important.